# How do I set a value to a textView?

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm working on a pretty simple project .. All I'm trying to do is changing the value of a textView.

Here is the **scenario**: There is a button and a textView. The default value of that textView is `no`. it should be `yes` when I click on that button. That's it.

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the JAVA code:

```
package ir.testApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TestAppActivity extends Activity {

    TextView text1;
    Button   btn1;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                text1.setText("yes");

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Currently it doesn't work. I mean nothing happens when I click on that button. Well what's wrong?

---

**Note:** When I put that button in the top of that textView, it works like a charm. So Why it won't work when the button is after that textView?

Comment: move the textview instantiation out of onclick.

Comment: Changing the view positions in LinearLayout shouldn't change anything. The code is pretty straightforward. For the sake of asking, are you sure you checked properly?

Comment: @Shriram how will that affect the outcome?

Comment: @Shriram I did, But still doesn't work ..

Comment: What is you xml layout file name? Is there any err? I try this code it is 1000000000000000000000000% ok.

Comment: What do you mean by Note?

Comment: @EnamulHaque I mean I dragged that textView in the under of that button and it works .. I thought probably knowing that would help you.

Comment: You are using LinearLayout. So if you dragged TextView It will place up or down the button but how it can work like charm?

Comment: @EnamulHaque That's exactly my question .. also as second note, I haven't installed Eclipse on my laptop, I'm using a portable version of it .. So maybe that's the problem.

Comment: It's not cause of it. Eclipse bundle not require to install. Can you run this code on device? What exactly you face? Is it run or show any compilation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the button position in XML only changes the View of your activity and can't resolve your problem.

Your are instantiating the TextView and setting a view to it in every click of button(!)
Instead of this, you have to instantiate the TextView like as your button and in your button clickListener just call `setText("yes")`.

```
public class TestAppActivity extends Activity {

    TextView text1;
    Button   btn1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                text1.setText("yes");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Edit Code Like this

```
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            text1.setText("yes");
        }
    });
```

### What is going on i don't know!! Code is 100000% ok. Nothing wrong.

Comment: Thanks . . . +1 .. Also I guess `100%` is enough .. no need to lots of zeros `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            text1.setText("yes");
        }
    });
```

> Note : Best way is, Initialize all UI Components at Outside of the `listeners`.